# Min and max in C using basics

Tags: c

This program is supposed to end when the user enters 0 and then show the count, sum, average, min and max. I am able to figure out the sum count and average but my min and max isn't working.

```
int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int average;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;    

    do {        
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &number);
        if (number > 0)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            sum += number;      
            min = number;
            max = number;

        }
        average = sum / count;

            if (number < min)
            {
                min = number;
            }
            else if (number > max)
            {
                max = number;
            }


    } while (number != 0);

    printf("count: %d\n",  count);
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    printf("average: %d\n", average);
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", min);
    printf("Maximum: %d\n", max);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Remove 
            `min = number;
            max = number;`. Do you need to handle negative numbers? If so, you should initialize `max`/`min` to +- infinity or integer max/min values.

Comment: Better yet, set `min = number` and `max = number` only if `count == 1` (i.e. only after the first value is entered).    Bear in mind that `sum/count` has undefined behaviour if `count == 0`, so better to check for that.

Answer (score 3):

First, initialize min and max with proper values.

```
int min = INT_MAX;
int max = INT_MIN;
```

Second, update min only when the input number less than current min.
Update max only when the input number is greater than the current max.

Comment: Tip: Indent code by 4 spaces. This can also be done by selecting the code and press the `{}` icon at the top of the input box.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int average;
    int min = INT_MAX;   // don't forget to include limits.h
    int max = INT_MIN;

    do {        
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &number);
        if (number > 0)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            sum += number;
            if (number < min)
            {
                min = number;
            }
            if (number > max)
            {
                max = number;
            }
        }
        else if (number < 0) 
        {
            printf("Negative value entered...skipping");
        }
    } while (number != 0);

    printf("count: %d\n",  count);
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    average = sum / count;
    printf("average: %d\n", average);
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", min);
    printf("Maximum: %d\n", max);

    system("pause");
}
```

You need to do two things:

1. Remove `min = number;` and `max = number` from the check `number > 0`. This is because, you are overriding the variables with the number value. This will lead to loss of previous `min` and `max` values, if any.
2. Instead of `int min = 0;` and `int max = 0`, use the upper and lower
   limit for integer data type. That is present in `limits.h`. You can use `INT_MAX` (2147483647) and `INT_MIN` (–2147483648).
3. There is another problem with your code. instead of `else if (number > max)`, it should be `if (number > max)`. For every number you need to check for *both* min and max values.
4. Also, the condition `if (number > 0)` should instead be `if (number != 0)`. This is because you want the program to end when user enters
   `0`, so for it to accept negative numbers that condition has to be
   changed.
5. Also, you need not calculate `average` every single time. Instead
   you can calculate after coming out of the loop.
6. Also, you need to move the checks for min and max inside the check
   `number != 0`. The reason for this is that you don't want to calculate min and max when `number == 0`.

Comment: @4386427, made the changes.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer but my program is supposed to work like this: it’s supposed to ask for positive integers till 0 is entered. And if negative value is entered its supposed to ask for a new number and discard all and any negative number from sum, count, average, min and max. And also i cant even go beyond  <stdio.h>.

Comment: @abrar, I have updated the code as per your requirement!

Comment: @abrar, if you are not allowed to use other standard header files, just use the values (mentioned in point 2) for `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

You used:

```
if (number > 0)
{
    count = count + 1;
    sum += number;      
    min = number;
    max = number;
}
```

Here, don't use:

```
min = number;
max = number;
```

Because, when number is greater than 0, min and max value will be set to the input number so the if and else if statement below it, will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Set the first number that scanf reads as initial value of min and initial value of max;This will always work whatever the numbers are.

```
if (count==1)
{
    min=number;
    max=number;
}
```